# How to change text colour across pages using mdframed

Tags: color, page-breaking, mdframed

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=0.85in, bottom=0.85in, left=0.85in, right=0.85in]{geometry}

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\textbf{Title:}

\textbf{Hello I am a title}
\end{center}

\begin{mdframed}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{4}
\section{Section title}

Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color.

Start this paragraph off with some text. \textcolor{red}{This is the part of the text I want to change to red but it breaks when there is a new page.}

\textcolor{green}{Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color. Let's fill up the space with text and see what happens when we change the color.} 


\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

For some reason when I try to change a section of the text to a different colour, it breaks when the page changes in the middle of the sentence. For example, the red text is red on page 1 but turns back to black on page 2. But the green text is completely changed to green because it does not span across two different pages.

[image]
[image]

How can I prevent this from happening so that the red text is completely red even across multiple pages?

Comment: use the tcolorbox package with `\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,use color stack]`. Or use an unicode engine, fontspec and font colors.

Comment: If I want to keep using mdframed, how do I implement the changes you suggested with the unicode engine, fontspec etc?

Comment: check the fontspec, it tells you how you can add color to a font. But I would recommend to use tcolorbox, it is much better than mdframed which has a number of bugs and is no longer actively maintained.

Comment: This is a color stack issue and you may have a look at [`pdfcol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcol) package, which is also used by `tcolorbox` option `use color stack`.